# Radio button Fee Clearance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three radio buttons that calculate fees. When you click the first radio button it has a drop down with a checkbox if you click the checkbox it adds $3.. if the user realizes that was a mistake and does not unclick the check box and clicks another radio button it does not remove the $3 from the total until the radio buttons are clicked at least twice.

The first two radio buttons are 78.25 and the 3rd is 88.25. Click first radio button 78.25 and then the checkbox will make it 81.25, then pretend your the user change your mind and hit the second radio button it should change it back to 78.25 when you click. But it does not and it keeps 81.25 if you click the third radio button it finally realizes it and corrects itself?

I have it set up to uncheck the checkbox when another radio button is checked but for some reason the fee is not changing instantly and is delayed for some reason. Can some one please assist?

If anyone has any suggestions or advice it would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/Ln1fnstb/2/

```js
$(function(){   //added by me
        $('#brandnewrv').click(function(){   
           calculateTotal();   
        });
    });

function rvsPrice()
{
    var rvPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["form"];
    var brandnewRv = document.getElementById('brandnewrv');
    if(brandnewRv.checked==true)
    {
        rvPrice=3;
    }
    return rvPrice;
}
//Setting Proof of Ownership Prices
 //Set up an associative array
 var title_prices = new Array();
 title_prices["MCO"]=78.25;
 title_prices["FL Title"]=78.25;
 title_prices["OOS Title"]=88.25;
 
 // Proof of Ownership Radio Buttons
function getProofOfOwnership()
{  
    var proofOfOwnership=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="form"
    var theForm = document.forms["form"];
    //Get a reference to the title the user Chooses name=ownerShip":
    var ownerShip = theForm.elements["ownership"];
    //Here since there are 4 radio buttons ownerShip.length = 4
    //We loop through each radio buttons
    for(var i = 0; i < ownerShip.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(ownerShip[i].checked)
        {
            proofOfOwnership = title_prices[ownerShip[i].value];
            //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
            //No reason to continue if we get a match
            break;
        }
    }
    //We return the proofOfOwnership
    return proofOfOwnership;
}
function calculateTotal()
{

    var titleFees = rvsPrice() + getProofOfOwnership();
    


    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Estimated Transfer Fees $"+titleFees;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form">
    <label><strong>Proof of Ownership</strong></label><br />
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="ownership" required="yes" message="Please select proof of ownership." value="MCO" onclick="calculateTotal()" onchange="statedropDown(this.value);"/>Manufacturer's Statement of Origin&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="ownership" value="FL Title" onclick="calculateTotal()" onchange="statedropDown(this.value);"/>Florida Certificate of Title&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="ownership" value="OOS Title" onclick="calculateTotal()" onchange="statedropDown(this.value);"/>Out-of-state Certificate of Title&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    
    <div id="div3" style="display:none">
<div class="clearfix">
       <select name="month1" id="month1" size="1">
    <option value="">Choose a Month</option>
    <option value="0">January</option>
    <option value="1">February</option>
    <option value="2">March</option>
    <option value="3">April</option>
    <option value="4">May</option>
    <option value="5">June</option>
    <option value="6">July</option>
    <option value="7">August</option>
    <option value="8">September</option>
    <option value="9">October</option>
    <option value="10">November</option>
    <option value="11">December</option>
</select>

            
</div>
</div>

<div id="div4" style="display:none">
<!---You are not qualified to see this form.--->
</div>
<div id="div5" style="display:none">
<p><label for='brandnewrv' class="inlinelabel">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Check if Brand new RV/Motor Home</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="brandnewrv" name='brandnewrv' onclick="calculateTotal()" /></p>
               
</div>
    <div id="totalPrice"></div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
function statedropDown(ownership) {
    if (ownership == "OOS Title") {
        document.getElementById("div3").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div4").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("div5").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("brandnewrv").checked = false;
  rvsPrice(); 
    } 
    else if (ownership == "FL Title") {
        document.getElementById("div4").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div3").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("div5").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("titlestates").selectedIndex = 0;
  document.getElementById("brandnewrv").checked = false;
  rvsPrice(); 
    }
 else if (ownership == "MCO") {
        document.getElementById("div5").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div3").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("div4").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("titlestates").selectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: Just a comment, if you're going to use jQuery, then use jQuery. Don't do `document.getElementById('totalPrice');` and inline event binding like `onclick="calculateTotal()"`. This whole script could be greatly simplified.

Comment: Your code calls that "rvsPrice()" function and always ignores the return value.

Comment: Thank you for your advice I am very new and learning as I go. I respect everyone who writes code man this is a learning process!! Even something like what I just posted is taking me hours of pondering and you would think it would be so simple! Its just sad how many people take programmers for granted they really can do amazing things!

Comment: @j08691 is right. Also if you look in the console, it says `getElementById` is null for this line: `var brandnewRv = document.getElementById('brandnewrv');`, no idea why. But if I use `$("#brandnewrv")` it returns the correct element.

Comment: @MattD The JavaScript Date API uses zero-based months.

Comment: @Pointy Huh, learn something new every day.

Comment: sounds good! I read somewhere that dates start at 0 that's the only reason I did it that way

Comment: @ZaneZ Actually, disregard what I said and listen to Pointy instead.

Comment: @artm that error stems from the "titlestates" reference, not "brandnewrv".

Comment: @MattD ha ha I didn't really mean that your advice was *wrong*, but that confusion *somewhere* is inevitable :)

Comment: @Pointy Still, I deleted the comment as a result because you're absolutely right (looked it up out of curiosity). Always love learning something new.

Comment: How's this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/94fhxb7u/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's some more complexity than there needs to be. I think the radio buttons really just need a "click" handler that calls a modified version of the "statedropDown" function, and no "change" handler. The "statedropDown" function should be changed so that it calls "calculateTotal()" at the end.  And that line that references "titlestates" needs to be commented out in the fiddle, since that part of the DOM isn't there.

```
<label class='radiolabel'>
<input type="radio" name="ownership" required="yes" message="Please select proof of ownership." value="MCO" onclick="statedropDown(this.value)">Manufacturer's Statement of Origin&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<label class='radiolabel'>
<input type="radio" name="ownership" value="FL Title" onclick="statedropDown(this.value)">Florida Certificate of Title&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<label class='radiolabel'>
<input type="radio" name="ownership" value="OOS Title" onclick="statedropDown(this.value)">Out-of-state Certificate of Title&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
```

and then

```
function statedropDown(ownership) {
    if (ownership == "OOS Title") {
        document.getElementById("div3").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div4").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("div5").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("brandnewrv").checked = false;
    } else if (ownership == "FL Title") {
        document.getElementById("div4").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div3").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("div5").style.display = 'none';
        //document.getElementById("titlestates").selectedIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById("brandnewrv").checked = false;
    } else if (ownership == "MCO") {
        document.getElementById("div5").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("div3").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("div4").style.display = 'none';
        //document.getElementById("titlestates").selectedIndex = 0;
    }
    calculateTotal();
}
```

[Here is the updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9pgmzm3k/) (I changed a couple of other minor things while tinkering with it, but I think the above changes are the key.)